# Trying to select information from database isn't working

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to code a game, in which the monsters are stored in a database. I'm trying to select a random monster from the database and store the information into variables that I can then use in the rest of the code. I also create the database within my main code. I'm getting the error "NameError: name 'random_monster_type' is not defined" and I'm not really sure why. Any insight would be very helpful.

```
from monster import Monster


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE monster (
           number integer,
           name text,
           type text,
           health integer,
           defence integer,
           attack integer,
           crit_chance integer,
           level integer,
           PRIMARY KEY (number)
           )""")

frost_troll = Monster('1', 'troll', 'frost', 90000, 0, 1, 10, 20)
earthy_troll = Monster('2', 'troll', 'earthy', 5000000, 1, 5, 0, 20)
lightning_zard = Monster('3', 'zard', 'lightning', 10000, 0, 10, 5, 1)
ogre_man = Monster('4', 'man', 'ogre', 750000, 25, 50, 0, 10)
chungus_rabbit = Monster('5', 'rabbit', 'chungus', 700, 0, 0, 0, 1)
bdsm_sonic = Monster('6', 'sonic', 'bdsm', 3000, 0, 0, 0, 1)

def insert_mon(mon):
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO monster VALUES (:number, :name, :type, :health, :defence, :attack, :crit_chance, :level)", {'number': mon.number, 'name': mon.name, 'type': mon.type, 'health': mon.health, 'defence': mon.defence, 'attack': mon.attack, 'crit_chance': mon.crit_chance, 'level': mon.level,})

insert_mon(frost_troll)
insert_mon(earthy_troll)
insert_mon(lightning_zard)
insert_mon(ogre_man)
insert_mon(chungus_rabbit)
insert_mon(bdsm_sonic)


c.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM monster")
temp_rand_half = c.fetchall()
temp_rand_half = (temp_rand_half[0])
temp_rand_half = list(temp_rand_half)
rand_half = temp_rand_half[0]
rand_half = int(rand_half)

def generate_monster():
    monnumber = random.randint(1,(rand_half))
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM monster WHERE number=:number", {'number': monnumber})
    monsterlist = (c.fetchone())
    print(monsterlist)
    random_monster_name = (monsterlist[1])
    random_monster_type = (monsterlist[2])
    random_monster_health = (monsterlist[3])
    monster_total_health = (monsterlist[3])
    monster_defence = (monsterlist[4])
    monster_attack = (monsterlist[5])
    monster_crit_chance = (monsterlist[6])
    monster_level = (monsterlist[7])
generate_monster()

conn.commit()

joined_random_monster = str((random_monster_type) + "_" + (random_monster_name))
themob = pygame.image.load(f"assets\\image\\{joined_random_monster}.png")
print(themob)

conn.commit()
```

this is my monster python file the main one imports:

```
class Monster:
    """A sample Monster class"""

    def __init__(self, number, name, type, health, defence, attack, crit_chance, level):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.health = health
        self.defence = defence
        self.attack = attack
        self.crit_chance = crit_chance
        self.level = level

    @property
    def email(self):
        return '{}.{} the destroyer'.format(self.name, self.type)

    @property
    def monstername(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.type)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Monster('{}', '{}', {})".format(self.name, self.type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to reference the variable `random_monster_type`, which was declared inside the function `generate_monster`, outside of the function.

To call the variable you have a few options.

**Solution 1: Using return**

```
# Solution using return.  
 
def foo(): 
    a = 'bar'
    return (100,a) 
 
print(foo()[0]) # 100
print(foo()[1]) # bar
```

**Solution 2: Using global**

```
# Solution using global.

def foo(): 
    global a 
    a = 'bar'
    return 100 
 
print(foo())  # 100
print(a)      # 'bar'
```

**Solution 3: Using function attributes**

```
# Solution using function attributes.

def foo():  
    foo.a = 'bar'
    return 100
 
print(foo()) # 100
print(foo.a) # 'bar'
```